# Advanced kinematics problem regarding $F = ma$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I really need help with this problem. Thank you for your time.

**Question:**

Look at the figure below.  Derive the formula for the magnitude of the force F⃗ exerted on the large block (mC) in the figure (Figure 1) such that the mass mA does not move relative to mC. Ignore all friction. Assume mB does not make contact with mC.

**Approach:**

I drew force diagrams to analyze the problem. I found out that F applied to mC must equal to the tension exerted on mA. What makes the problem difficult is that the tension of mC is tilted, which means that the tension of mC is not simply 9.81 * mB.

[image: Problem Diagram]

Comment: Acceleration is vector. Treat it as such.

Comment: This is not a kinematics problem, it's a dynamics problem.  And considering that "advanced" usually means "graduate level or above" here, I would argue that this is not "advanced", either.

Comment: Resolving forces horizontally and vertically on each block yields 6 equations in 6 unknowns, which are easily solved. Note that all 3 masses accelerate at the same rate horizontally, and since $m_A$ and $m_B$ are connected, $m_B$ is stationary in the vertical direction.

Comment: @michael - there is no reason why the masses accelerate at the same rate horizontally - B is swinging so it can do its own thing… so initially it will not move horizontally. Until the angle of the string connecting B to the pulley is non-vertical, it will not accelerate horizontally.

Comment: @Floris I agree that if we begin with a non-accelerating system $m_B$ is free to do its own thing. However, I do not believe that is the point of this question.

Comment: @Michael agree - but this was what you explicitly stated in your comment ("all three masses accelerate at the same rate horizontally") - I just wanted to make sure that this didn't lead to possible confusion.

Answer (score 1):

"I found out that F applied to mC must equal to the tension exerted on mA" is wrong

F=(m_a+m_b+m_c)*a

T=m_a*a

T_x=m_b * a

T_y=m_b *g

T^2=T_x^2+T_y^2

Replace and get

F=[(m_a+m_b+m_c)*m_b*g]/sqrt(m_a^2-m_b^2)

Comment: Please do not give away the full solution, as the OP will never learn physics when given the answers.